# ST ST25R95 - NFC chip - Impedance of transmission lines

Tags: impedance, transmission-line

I will supply the chip with 3.3V, and the datasheet of ST25R95 IC shows it has a ZOUT of 27R at this condition.
[image]

There is a circuit between NFC antenna/coil/inductor and the IC, the LC filter and matching circuit:
[image]

My doubt is about the black lines shown on picture above, the transmission lines. Should they have 50 ohms? or 27 ohms? I think it should have standard 50 ohms but I would like to have sure about that.

Here is the datasheet if you need: https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/st25r95.pdf

Regards.

**EDIT:**

There is a distance of around 10mm between the transmitter pads and the antenna:

[image]

**EDIT 2:**

Calculation of microstrip with AppCad of Avago Technologies

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *My doubt is about the black lines shown on picture above, the
>   transmission lines. Should they have 50 ohms? or 27 ohms? I think it
>   should have standard 50 ohms but I would like to have sure about that.*

The device operates at 13.56 MHz and the wavelength of 13.56 MHz is 22 metres in free space and about 15 metres on a typical PCB. So, the golden rule is that if your tracks are longer than about one-tenth the wavelength then you should start to consider using transmission line calculations.

Are the tracks likely to be close to anything like 1.5 metres long is the question you should consider. If not then don't worry about matching because it won't make a difference practically.

<sub>I've used 13.56 MHz because the signals are largely sinewave at 13.56 MHz. If it were a clock of 13.56 MHz then I'd be considering t-line math if the track length was more than 20 cm.</sub>

Comment: Hi. I have understood your "trance length greater than one-tenth of the wavelenght" rule. Thanks. I have updated the original topic... So there is no difference in practice? But in theory, 50 ohms would be ideal?

Comment: 50 ohms would be OK but there is no ideal at this frequency with short PCB tracks. I'd just concentrate on making the tracks thick enough (and then a bit more) to handle the current for the magnetic antenna and not worry about what theoretical t-line impedance it has because it won't matter.

Comment: Ok. My traces of RF side are all 12mils. This gives me a t-line of 50 ohms microstrip @ copper thickness of 0.5oz and 0.18mm of distance between the top side RF traces and the GND plane. So you suggest to increase the RF traces width to 15mils for example?

Comment: Make the traces suitable for the current they are handling - that's all I'm suggesting. If 12 thou is good for whatever RMS current flows and that happens to be (coincidentally) a 50 ohm transmission line that's cool. If you need fatter traces and that ends up being a 25 ohm t-line then no problem.

Comment: Hi. https://www.eeweb.com/tools/external-pcb-trace-max-current . According to this calculator, a 12 mils width trace can withstand to up to 0.55A, and thats very ok for the application, because the transceiver is 0.3W only. And please check again the bottom of the topic, I have added the AppCad software screen showing the 50 ohms result.

Comment: Yeah, looks a nice calculator.